# What is the integral of a function from $\infty$ to $\infty$?

Tags: integration, limits, definite-integrals

I apologize in advance for my bad English, I am italian.

I took a Calculus exam today, and one of the exercises was:
$$ \lim_{x\to\infty} \int_x^{x+1/x}e^{t^2}dt $$
I answered $0$ even though I knew that $\int_x^xf(x)dx=0$ is only true for a finite 
$x$, in fact I was wrong.

I could not ask the teacher for the right answer and I still can't see a way to calculate this limit.

PS: I guess my exam was pretty similar to the one you call Calculus I, so please do not use advanced theorems.

Comment: Hint: If $f$ is increasing and $a<b$, then $\int_a^b f\ge (b-a)f(a)$.

Comment: It's not a good idea to think of this as $\int_\infty^\infty$.  The answer changes depending on whether you look at the interval $[x,x+1/x]$ (which is already very narrow) or an even narrower interval like, say, $[x,x+e^{-x^3}]$.  So abstracting both endpoints to $\infty$ loses sight of this, just as an $\infty/\infty$ limit depends critically on the specific functions involved.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

$f(t)=e^{t^2}$ is an increasing function over $\mathbb{R}^+$, hence

$$\int_{x}^{x+\frac{1}{x}} e^{t^2}\,dt \geq \int_{x}^{x+\frac{1}{x}}e^{x^2}\,dt = \frac{e^{x^2}}{x} $$
and the limit is just $+\infty$.

Comment: That works, but this property has not been taught us during the course.

Comment: Read carefully, he just used an elementary inequality. For all $t \in \left[x, x+\frac{1}{x}\right]$, we have $e^{t^2} \geq e^{x^2}$, so integrate both sides w.r.t to $t$. In his second integral, $e^{x^2}$ is constant with respect to $t$.

Comment: Meaning: he did **not** compute $\int e^{t^2}\,{\rm d}t$ in any way.

Comment: Now I see. Very clever, thank you!